# How do i call 'f.prototype' correctly?

Tags: javascript, nomenclature

Given a javascript function

```
var f = function();
```

as far as i understand, i would call `Object.getProtoypeOf(f)` "f's prototype".

What is the correct term for `f.prototype`?

"The Prototype objects constructed with f as constructor will get" sounds a little verbose ;)

Comment: What's wrong with f's prototype?

Comment: There is a difference between those, testable with `f.prototype != Object.getPrototypeOf(f)`. `f.prototype` is the Prototype objects created via `new f()` get, but it's not f's protoype

Comment: Take a look at [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf). `f.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(f)`. Btw, are you trying to do something with `prototype`s or just wondering about them?

Comment: I don't understand how `f.__proto__ == Object.getPrototypeOf(f)` relates to my question. I am not wondering _how_ prototypes work, i am wondering, what the correct terms are to discuss them.

Comment: f.constructor.prototype this is same as Object.getPrototypeOf(f) maybe you find answer on your question here http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/UCmW8/

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    alert(this.name + ' says hi!');
};

var matt = new Person('Matt');
matt.sayHi() // alerts 'Matt says hi!'

console.log('matt.prototype',                matt.prototype);
console.log('Object.getPrototypeOf(matt)',   Object.getPrototypeOf(matt));
console.log('Person.prototype',              Person.prototype);
console.log('Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)', Object.getPrototypeOf(Person));
```

What does this produce?

[image: prototypes output]

First `matt.prototype` is `undefined`. Functions have a prototype object, and when that function used as a constructor, instances get to use properties of it, but the instances don't have a `prototype` property themselves.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(matt)` finds the real prototype. And as you can see, this is the same as `Person.prototype`.  It allows you to get the prototype, without having a reference to the constructing function.

Lastly, if we try `Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)` we get something weird.  Our constructor function, is a function after all.  Think of functions you create as instances of some `Function` constructor, with it's own prototype.  So you are fetching the prototype object of *all functions* when you do this.

Comment: Your post is accurate, but does not answer my question. I was not wondering what the difference between f.prototype and f's prototype is. I was looking for the correct Terms to discuss them.